# android - button clicking and screen touching won't work together

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouch

I am trying to have multi-touch in my app, but button touching and screen holding don't work together.  I want a button to be responsive even if I have a finger on a non-button part of the screen.  However, the button doesn't work if the screen is being held down and the screen doesn't work if the button is being held downHere is something similar to my code.

```
package com.example.amitjoshi.am6;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{
    private TextView message;
    private Button button;
    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout = 
(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDetails = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
    buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
    button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListener());
    //gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
}
private class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        MainActivity.this.message.setText("Clicked");
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    //message.setText("onDown");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    //message.setText("onShowPress");
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    message.setText("onSingleTapUp");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    message.setText("Swiped");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    //message.setText("onLogPress");
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    message.setText("Swiped");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want a button to be responsive even if I have a finger on a non-button

You cannot have that with framework containers.

Comment: Are there any other types of containers that would allow this to happen?

Comment: Perhaps, because it's doable yet no system one offers such feature. You can try writing your own **if** this feature really is needed

Comment: and how would I start doing that?  Which classes should I extend?